# how to change the position of the picture and the text in the html of the bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am newbie with bootstrap 5 and here is my problem.

As you can see in this picture

[image: my problem]

In my page, at the top, the google icon and all the texts are at the left side, and in the picture, the texts and the google picture are at the left side too.

I want to change the position of the google icon, the "Home, About ..." texts, all the text "I am dreaming ..." and the Google picture to the right side a little bit. And change the "I am dreaming ..." up a little bit.

Here is my code

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/project2.3
```

Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I added just `<div>` with `class="text-center"` for image

```html
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-center ">
            <h1 class="display pt-5">
                I am dreaming
            </h1>
            <p class="lead">
                Still dreaming
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg text-white">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> read more
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="img/ggbook.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Outupt

[image]

Comment: yeah thanks for using some painting program to  draw for me, that is exactly what I want to do. So, how can I code to make my front to be like yours ?

Comment: Answer is updated please check it

Comment: I have been added div with text-center as you recommended but the result is still not changed ? Could you please check it again ?

Comment: You need to remove d-none d-lg-block from img tag

Comment: Just copy and paste my code snippet